# What prop or function does React SurveyJS use to achieve different rendering for Survey Creator designer vs prieview or Form Library

Tags: surveyjs

I am trying to create a custom React element and renderer for SurveyJS Survey Creator, I would like it to render differently in the survey designer so that I can control the properties from the element, similarilty to the added adornements to dropdown or image pickers that let you add or remove choices in the designer but the rendered adornements go away in the prieview and the actual Form Library render.
I am following this example: https://surveyjs.io/form-library/examples/create-custom-question-renderer/reactjs#content-code

Answer (score 0):

Each survey element (Survey, Page, Question and so on) the the `isDesignMode` property that can be set via the following code: `survey.setDesignMode(true);`